# Pepper cancel running animation

Tags: android, pepper

Currently developping on a Pepper robot (Android dev), I'm trying to use some "basic" animations (from QiSQK lib).
For instance, when calling a WS, I'm starting a "think" animation using animation/animate. Then, when the WS call ends, I try to use another animation ("showing the tablet").

I saw that Pepper can't animate twice if the previous animation isn't finished/cancelled.
So, I used `requestCancellation()`, but it didn't stop the animation.
I also used `cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)`, didn't stop either.

So, I can't chain 2 animations without waiting the previous animation to stop (my WS call = 3-4s max).

Any idea ?

Example :

```
private var animate: Future<Animate>? = null

fun animate(animRes: Int) {
        animate?.requestCancellation()

        AnimationBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withResources(animRes)
                .buildAsync()
                .thenConsume { futureAnimation ->
                    animate = AnimateBuilder
                            .with(qiContext)
                            .withAnimation(futureAnimation?.value)
                            .buildAsync()
                    animate?.andThenConsume {
                       it.async().run()
                    }
                }
}
```

Thx,
Bastien.

Comment: WS == Web Service?

Comment: @Barry yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out my issue.
Actually, I was storing the `animate` reference when creating the object like this :

```
animate = AnimateBuilder
                  .with(qiContext)
                  .withAnimation(futureAnimation?.value)
                  .buildAsync()
```

So, I printed my objects (like every `Future`'s used in my callbacks), then I found that after using `it.async().run()` from my animate `andThenConsume` callback, which returns the running animation reference, is different from the one I created before (was thinking reusing same old ref).

So, instead, here my new (working) code :

```
fun animate(animRes: Int) {
        //Cancelling possible running animation to display a new one
        animate?.requestCancellation()

        AnimationBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withResources(animRes)
                .buildAsync()
                .thenConsume { futureAnimation ->
                    AnimateBuilder
                            .with(qiContext)
                            .withAnimation(futureAnimation?.value)
                            .buildAsync()
                            .andThenConsume {
                                animate = it.async().run() as Future<Animate>
                            }
                }
}
```